# Enviar datos de @foreach a una sub-view

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8

estoy intentando usar una vista dentro de otra en Laravel pero cuando lo intento hacer se me presenta el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando pasar la variable $cliententes a mi view principal de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pense que solo tendria que pasarle el @import a mi blade principal pero no me sirvio.

Comment: El error es por que literalmente estás tratando de acceder a varias claves en un string, $clientes solo tiene como valor el texto `id`, no veo entonces de donde va a leer el nombre o el apellido

Comment: Hola gracias por tu rápida respuesta, de que forma podría pasar los datos al view por que cuando defino **$clientes = [];** como arreglo vacío no se me presenta ningún problema y puedo ver el view.

Comment: Asigna como valor de la variable `$clientes` la consulta que te devuelva los datos que estás tratando de imprimir en la vista, de otro modo seguirá fallando

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!!!
Me demore un poco pero lo logre cambie la ruta de la siguiente forma
**$datos['clientes'] = clientes::paginate(5);**
**return view('dashboard',$datos);**